# Hide input field from vuejs-datepicker

Tags: css, vue.js, datepicker

I am using vuejs-datepicker in one of my vue project. I want to hide the default input and show the Calendar when user press a button. I am trying to have the `<datepicker/>` inside a div apply css for the div so that I can hide it.

```
<div class="datePickerDiv">
   <datepicker class="date" ref="datepick"></datepicker>
</div>

<style scoped>
.datePickerDiv {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -40px;
}
.datePickerDiv input {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}
</style>
```

But its not working as I expect. Sample https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-sea-qfuix?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:742-910

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [the `>>>` combinator](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors) in order to deeply select the `input` tag:

```
.datePickerDiv >>> input {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}
```

This is because you're using the `scoped` attribute on your style tag. `scoped` will only work to apply styling to child components directly referenced in your current Vue component. In this case, datepicker is creating its own child `input` which will not be affected by the style, unless you use the deep selector shown above.

Answer (score 1):

For applying style in your date picker tag, use `input-class` instead of only class. The styling **does not work** on the default scoped style tags, so add another style tag beneath your scoped style tag like follows:

```
<style scoped>
---your scoped Styles ----
</style>

<style >
-- Apply your unscoped style over vue date picker here ---
</style>
```

Example

```
<datepicker input-class="date" ref="datepick"></datepicker>
<style>
.date {
  display: none !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add prop input-class with class hide-input. This will apply the hide-input class to the input element. Read more about props [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker#available-props).

```js
<datepicker input-class="hide-input"></datepicker>
```

```css
.hide-input{
  display: none !important;
}
```